# How to combine all strings in a nested-list?

Tags: list, dart, fold

I have a list, which contains multi-level nested lists. Each list can have strings and other type instances.

E.g.

```
var list = [ 'a', 'w', ['e', ['f', new Object(), 'f'], 'g'], 't', 'e'];
```

I want to write a function (say `compress`) to combine strings with their siblings, and leave other type instances untouched, and finally, get a list which doesn't have nested list.

compress(list) {
      // how to ?
   }

And the result of `compress(list)` will be:

```
['awef', new Object(), 'fgte']
```

Is it quick and clear solution for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Terse and functional FTW

```dart
List compress(Iterable iterable) => concat(flatten(iterable));

Iterable flatten(Iterable iterable) => 
    iterable.expand((e) => e is Iterable ? flatten(e) : [e]);

List concat(Iterable iterable) => iterable.fold([], (list, e) => 
    list..add((e is String && list.isNotEmpty && list.last is String)
        ? list.removeLast() + e : e));
```

Comment: Whats that `list..add` doing? Executing `add`, but returning `list`? Still missing some kind of function application operator like Haskell and XQuery know them... `List compress => flatten . concat;` would be really cute.

Comment: Yes. This is a method cascade. The expression evaluates to list, so the function returns the list, but allows add to be called in the same expression. I actually like your answer better, i.e. it's clearer. I was just playing around to see how short I could get the code.

Comment: Sweet, I was disgusted of that `return list` all the time. I definitely prefer your `flatten`, although `concat` got a bit hard to read.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think using flatten using expand is also lazy evaluated, at least at the top level. i.e. it returns an Iterable rather than a list. Function composition would be cool - need a different syntax though, as dot is taken. Unfortunately Dart can't really be a functional language without proper tail calls. However it sounds like the Ecmascript spec may get proper tail calls soon. This means that later versions of Dart should be able to have proper tail calls too. This would enable all sorts of functional shenanigans.

Comment: Well, [there's Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_JavaScript_Problem). ;) But playin' around with Dart for a while was fun. By the way, I could break down `concat` to two lines by shorting the names a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

This consists of two problems, a very standard one (flattening a list) and then joining the strings adequately.

```dart
flatten(Iterable l) => l.fold([], (List list, element) {
  if (element is Iterable)
    list.addAll(flatten(element));
  else
    list.add(element);
  return list;
});

concat(Iterable l) => l.fold([], (List list, element) {
  if (element is String && !list.isEmpty && list.last is String)
    list.add(list.removeLast() + element);
  else
    list.add(element);
  return list;
});

void main() {
  var nested = [ 'a', 'w', ['e', ['f', new Object(), 'f'], 'g'], 't', 'e'];
  print(concat(flatten(nested));
}
```

---

*Update:*

An alterantive `concat`, inspired by Greg Lowe (doing exactly the same like my "large" and his one, but even more condense):

```dart
concat(Iterable list) => list.fold([], (List xs, x) => xs..add(
    x is String && !xs.isEmpty && xs.last is String ? xs.removeLast() + x : x));
```

You can combine his and my functions as you want, they're doing exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a StringBuffer for the concatenation if you have a lot of strings.
My guess is that in most cases it is not a problem.

```dart
List compress(List list) {
  var sb = new StringBuffer();
  List result = [];
  List compressRec(List list) {
    for (var element in list) {
      if (element is String) {
        sb.write(element);
      } else if (element is List) {
          compressRec(list);
      } else {
        if (sb.isNotEmpty()) {
          result.add(sb.toString());
          sb.clear();
        }
        result.add(element);
      }
    }
  }
  compressRec(list)
  if (sb.isNotEmpty()) {
    result.add(sb.toString());
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess :

```dart
compress(List l, [List p]) => l.fold(p != null ? p : [], (List t, e) {
  if (e is String) {
    if (t.isEmpty || t.last is! String) t.add(e);
    else t.add(t.removeLast() + e);
  } else if (e is List) compress(e, t);
  else t.add(e);
  return t;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt

```dart
List flatten(List l) {
  List result = [''];
  int cur = 0;

  var add = (f) {
    if(f is String) {
      result[cur] += f;
    } else {
      result.add(f);
      result.add('');
      cur += 2;
    }
  };

  l.forEach((e) {
    if(e is List) {
      flatten(e).forEach((e) => add(e));
    } else {
      add(e);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```